# How to create a partial unique index only for documents that do not contain a field?

Tags: mongodb, partial, unique-constraint

I'm trying to create a unique index on a collection. This unique index should apply only to documents that do **not** contain the `deleted_at` field.

I tried:

```
db.collection.createIndex({a: 1, b:1},
    {
        unique: true,
        partialFilterExpression: {
            deleted_at: {$exists: false}
        }
    }
)
```

But this raises an error saying that `not` is not supported in `createIndex` (I guess the `$exists: false` is converted to a `$not: {$exists: true}`).

I then tried a workaround:

```
db.collection.createIndex({a: 1, b:1},
    {
        unique: true,
        sparse: false,
        partialFilterExpression: {
            deleted_at: {$type: 'null'}
        }
    }
)
```

This index is valid but does not do what I want. It only applies to documents that do contain `deleted_at` but have a value of `null`. This is not acceptable because the existing application uses queries with `exists` all over the place to exclude deleted stuff, so I cannot simply migrate the data to include the field setting it to null.

**Does Mongo support a way to create an index, and apply that index only to documents *not* containing a specific field?**

If the answer is no how can I try to enforce, *from the DB*, the uniqueness of the elements of a connection? My application will rely on the DB raising an error in case of race conditions when inserting elements.

Comment: This index should solve your requirements: `db.collection.createIndex({a: 1, b:1, deleted_at:1},{unique:true})` If you insert new document without `deleted_at` field (and there is another document with the same `a` and `b` values as new document), it will raise an error

Comment: @Valijon  Uhm, yes and no... maybe I can make that work for my case because `deleted_at` is a date, but I would like a general answer that creates an index only on documents without a certain field. Anyway, thank you.